# read json file form host showing white Screen in activity How can i solve this?

Tags: android, json

i want to read a JSON file from my  host I made the internet permission and their is no exception in run just a White Screen and i don't 
   know what wrong,How can I solve this?
  i expect a list that i made
    [json link here](https://mohammedhemaid.000webhostapp.com/jsonTest.json)
     The code is following

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.moham.twitter_ai;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   private List<tweets> tweetsList = new ArrayList<>();
   private ListView listView;
   private tweetAdapter madapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.list);
    madapter = new tweetAdapter(this, tweetsList);
    listView.setAdapter(madapter);
    gettweets();
 }

void gettweets() {

    String url = "https://mohammedhemaid.000webhostapp.com/jsonTest.json";

    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, 
     new Response.Listener<String>() {


        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                String tweetText = object.getString("text");
                String date = object.getString("timestamp_ms");
                JSONObject user = object.getJSONObject("user");
                String name = user.getString("name");
                String screen_name = user.getString("screen_name");


                    tweets tw = 
            new tweets(name, screen_name, tweetText,date);
                    tweetsList.add(tw);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.getMessage()
            ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(postRequest);
  }
}
```

Adapter :

```
 /**
 * Created by moham on 27-Apr-18.
  */

 public class tweetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<tweets> {


public tweetAdapter(@NonNull Context context,List<tweets> tweets) {
    super(context, 0,tweets);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull 
  ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    tweets currentTweets = getItem(position);

    TextView name = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
    name.setText(currentTweets.getName());

    TextView screenName = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_screen_name);
    screenName.setText(currentTweets.getScreenName());

    TextView tweetText = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_tweet_text);
    tweetText.setText(currentTweets.getTweet());

    Date dateObject = new Date(currentTweets.getTimeStamp());

    TextView dateView =  listItemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
    // Format the date string (i.e. "Mar 3, 1984")

    dateView.setText(currentTweets.getTimeStamp());

    return listItemView;
  }
}
```

error:(logCat)

JsonFile:

```
{"created_at":"Mon Mar 26 18:24:04 +0000 2018","id":978336799520100352,"id_str":"978336799520100352","text":"Ik wilde gwn een gratis gun en die krijg ik nu dus \ud83d\ude02 https:\/\/t.co\/AH38GYbUfk","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":964059877223084032,"id_str":"964059877223084032","name":"Wessel hoek","screen_name":"teddybeer025","location":null,"url":null,"description":"ik speel fortnite op de ps4","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":2,"friends_count":10,"listed_count":1,"favourites_count":17,"statuses_count":7,"created_at":"Thu Feb 15 08:52:40 +0000 2018","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":"nl","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"F5F8FA","profile_background_image_url":"","profile_background_image_url_https":"","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/964065505513476102\/4hCVGSKG_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/964065505513476102\/4hCVGSKG_normal.jpg","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/AH38GYbUfk","expanded_url":"https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/app\/id1333542838","display_url":"itunes.apple.com\/app\/id13335428\u2026","indices":[53,76]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"nl","timestamp_ms":"1522088644281"}
```

What Im I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding the empty list before you getting, so when you add items to the list the adapter dosn't know it needs to refresh. After you've added all new items to your list, call:

```
madapter.notifyDatasetChanged()
```

To refresh your adapter.

Moreover, you json doesn't seem to be a valid one. I've tested it with [JsonLint](https://jsonlint.com/) and it looks like a list of tweets but it isn't enclosed in [] nor separated by commas.

If your json was a valid array of tweets, your code should look like this:

```
JSONArray objs = new JSONArray(response);
for(JSONObject object : objs){
   String tweetText = object.getString("text");
   String date = object.getString("timestamp_ms");
   JSONObject user = object.getJSONObject("user");
   String name = user.getString("name");
   String screen_name = user.getString("screen_name");
   tweets tw = 
                new tweets(name, screen_name, tweetText,date);
                        tweetsList.add(tw);
}
madapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```